# What is the use of this code that "Detects zero bytes inside a 32 bit integer"?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

Original post
http://bits.stephan-brumme.com/null.html

1. What does this code do? (was answered, thanks)
2. Where is it used?

   ```
   bool hasZeroByteSimple(unsigned int x)
   {
       if ((x & 0x000000FF) == 0)
           return true;
       if ((x & 0x0000FF00) == 0)
           return true;
       if ((x & 0x00FF0000) == 0)
           return true;
       if ((x & 0xFF000000) == 0)
           return true;

       return false;
   }
   ```

Comment: To check simply if an unsigned int has a zero byte?

Comment: so, if unsigned int consists of only 1s, it will return false?

Comment: editted the question, decided to ask what is the point of finding zero byte

Comment: see my answer below, re: finding a null terminator of a string.

Comment: thanks, i was using my nokia browser to ask this question, haven't noticed that it plain-texted my code

Comment: "hasZeroByteSimple" isn't used anywhere. You might as well test 4 bytes for zeroes as bytes. The other version is used sometimes to speed up looking for a zero - often the nul character at the end of a string.

Comment: From the page you linked to: *"One of the most prominent example of detecting zeroes is strlen. To improve performance many bytes are examined in parallel."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking if an `unsigned int` has a 0x00 byte in it, some examples below:

```
0x11223300
0x11220033
0x11002233
0x00112233
```

As a counter-example, though this number has zeros in it, it does not have a zero `byte`:

```
0x70801206 (bytes: 0x70, 0x80, 0x12, 0x06)
```

As a second counter-example, though this number has 8 zero bits in a row, it does not have a zero `byte` if you break the number into its four constituent bytes:

```
0x10023456 (bytes: 0x10, 0x02, 0x34, 0x56)
```

**EDIT:**  In response to your additional question, you would look for a zero byte when you are trying to find the NULL terminator in a string, like if you were calculating the equivalent of the the `strlen()` function.  Instead of going byte-by-byte, you can look at 4 bytes at one time (unsigned int).

Comment: ah, ok, thanks.  Hate to beg like this ... can you accept my answer?  I'm kind of a n00b on stackoverflow and I'm trying to get some rep.

Comment: It is worth noting that the code will fail if `sizeof(unsigned int) != 4 || CHAR_BIT != 8`.

Answer (score 2):

It assumes that `unsigned int` is 32 bits (4 bytes) wide, and checks whether at least one byte of `x` is zero.

The author argues that this can be used to speed up `strlen()`, by quickly detecting whether there is a NUL terminator within a block of four consecutive characters. If there isn't, `strlen()` can move on to the next block; if there is, it would need to re-examine the four bytes to see which of them was NUL.

Comment: so what is the point of finding a zero byte? i mean, where is it used?

Answer (score 2):

This code just checks if the number has a zero byte, this means it's a byte composed of 8 bits all set to zero.

0xFF is 255, so if x & 255 is zero, this means that the last byte has all zero bits. 0xFF00 is 255^2, so in this case the second byte is all zero, and so on until the 4th byte.

Answer (score 1):

Just like the name says, the function checks, if the parameter (4byte unsigned int) contains at least one byte, which is completely zero.

Answer (score 1):

`x` consists of four bytes. It checks if either of those bytes are zero.

Answer (score 1):

It is intended to be the equivalent of:

```
return memchr(&x, 0, sizeof x);
```

That is, it searches for a zero byte in the memory occupied by `x` and returns true or false according to whether it finds such a byte or not.